# traceroute command: replacement or alternative

Tags: linux, centos

On recent Linux based operating systems there is no `ifconfig` and `traceroute`. Some functionality has been incorporated into the `ip` utility (see [here](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/) for examples), but I have not found a replacement for the traceroute command.

I know that I can do `yum install net-tools` or `yum install traceroute` when I am on CentOS or RHEL but our servers come preinstalled without that command and while we are allowed to sudo certain commands installing additional software is always a problem

Comment: You have to negotiate a baseline/template with a bare minimum of mandatory commands to be able to do your work. You are trying to solve a political problem with a technical workaround. Escalate this need to your superior(s).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I agree, but only 99% ;-) `ifconfig` for example is outdated and can be replaced by `ip addr show`. My hope was that there is also a "new-style" command that jumps in for traceroute

Comment: `tracepath` and `mtr` are available by default in `Ubuntu 20.04`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It strongly depends on your configuration.
I've got two options for you:

1. Compile `traceroute` by yourself. Use compiled binary without any problem.
2. If there is `busybox` package installed on your system, then you can simply use it's binary as `traceroute`. Just link `busybox` binary as `traceroute` (in case of my system it is `ln -s /bin/busybox traceroute`), and then use this link to act as `traceroute`: `./traceroute google.com`.

Comment: Any admin worth his salt, if doing a minimum bare install, wont install development tools in a minimum vm nowadays. Long are gone the days vmtools had to be compiled in. If I do not need backup and Nagios agents, I can supply a barebones Debian VM around 200MB for a DNS/DHCP server (not trying to diminish the merit of the answer)

Answer (score 48):

Try if command "tracepath" available

Comment: available in Linux Mint 21

Answer (score 20):

The utility `mtr` (aka Mike's traceroute, aka Matt's traceroute) has been described as "traceroute on steroids", and gets favorable reviews [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/net-admin/traceroute-alternatives/), [here](https://www.netadmintools.com/traceroute-alternatives/#MTR) and in [this SE Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/189808/831935). It seems to have been around for a while.

I use `mtr` on macOS occasionally to evaluate DNS options, and it seems to work very well. I got my copy through [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). It comes pre-installed on at least some Linux distros (e.g. Ubuntu 20.04). It's also available through its [GitHub site](https://github.com/traviscross/mtr).

Finally, there's a [How-To guide for using mtr](https://vitux.com/how-to-use-the-linux-mtr-command/).

Comment: available by default in Linux Mint 21

Answer (score 5):

While `traceroute` is no longer available in recent Linux distro, `traceroute6` is still available but only for IPv6.

```
wolf@linux:~$ whatis traceroute6
traceroute6 (8)      - traces path to a network host
wolf@linux:~$
```

If you want to run it against IPv4, use `tracepath` or `mtr`.

You don't have to install or compile it separately as it's already there in the OS.

```
wolf@linux:~$ whatis tracepath 
tracepath (8)        - traces path to a network host discovering MTU along this path
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ whatis mtr
mtr (8)              - a network diagnostic tool
wolf@linux:~$
```